# How to select next row after select in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this issue, I need your help:

```
EmpNo   Shift_Date  Shift1 shift2    stamp_Date   stamp_Time    stamp_Type
 426    2015-04-12  A                2015-04-12   10:09:00.000  I
 426    2015-04-15  B       C        2015-04-15   23:46:00.000  I
 426    2015-04-15  B       C        2015-04-15   23:45:00.000  O
 426    2015-04-16  OF               2015-04-16   07:02:00.000  O
 426    2015-04-17  A                2015-04-17   07:34:00.000  I
 426    2015-04-18  A                2015-04-18   08:05:00.000  I
 426    2015-04-19  A                2015-04-19   10:29:00.000  I
 426    2015-04-24  A                2015-04-24   07:22:00.000  I
```

I need to select only the rows with `value ='C'` and the next row each time.

Comment: post queries you have tried

Comment: Is this c# or vb.net? I can't see any value field either, are you talking about "shift2"? Read [ask]

Comment: Which rows do you want to return?

Comment: "next row" based on what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query can be written as:

```
; WITH Base AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Shift_Date) RN FROM #Table1 
)

, WithC AS (
    SELECT * FROM Base WHERE Shift2 = 'C'
)

SELECT * FROM WithC
UNION
SELECT WithCNext.* FROM WithC C LEFT JOIN Base WithCNext ON C.RN + 1 = WithCNext.RN
```

You use `ROW_NUMBER()` to give a sequential number to all the rows (note that you have to select an ordering, I have used `Shift_Date`). Then you take the rows with `Shift2 = 'C'`, then you `UNION` them with the rows that have a `RN + 1`

No SQL Fiddle today because (at least for me) it isn't working :-(